# Xamarin.Forms Android/iOS HttpClient.Timeout not respected

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms (I have encountered this on Android with v3.1.0.697729 and iOS with v3.4.0.1008975) app where I make http requests.  Whatever value `HttpClient.Timeout` is set to, if the requests exceeds 100s (which I believe is the default timeout value) then it times out.  This does not seem to be an uncommon issue and I have found some information about the problem.  In [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/388530/httpclienttimeout-values-set-above-default-100-sec.html) it is suggested that for Android a work around is to set `ConnectTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` on `AndroidClientHandler`.  However if I pass a new `AndroidClientHandler`, with appropriate timeouts set, to my `HttpClient` instead of using the default, I get the following error: `encoding 'identity' is not supported. only supports gzip or deflate encoding.`.  As far as I can tell the settings on the `AndroidClientHandler` related to this are set to the same values as on the default `HttpClientHandler` and I cannot find any other information about this error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? or if there is a different/better workaround for this timeout issue?

Comment: Only if the requests exceeds 100s it works?

Comment: Well I assume regardless of what you set the timeout too, it will timeout after 100s as that is the default.  I've not tried setting it lower.

Comment: Ok,the default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).Do you check your connect URL is valid？Or add the permission for android? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I can see on the server that the request was received successfully and in fact returned a 200, it's just the client end is timing out too early.  I created a little demo app here that calls httpstat.us: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rukqqp2yyji5ug9/HttpClientTimeoutApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Just got round to testing what happens when timeout is less than 100s and that seems to work.  It appears that it is only when the timeout is set to greater than 100s that it is ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately,I found this may be an issue(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/388530/httpclienttimeout-values-set-above-default-100-sec.html).I think Xamarin will solved this soon.If want to set over 100s .Suggest that use `Thread` to do that first.

Comment: I think that's the same link I linked in my original post.  What do you mean by using `Thread`?

Comment: If the timeout period is long, it can be timed by the thread. Just like creating a new thread through the timer to ensure the accuracy of the timeout.